Can including a covariate in the outcome model that wasn't included in the PS model introduce bias
Can including a covariate in the outcome model that wasn't included in the PS model introduce bias in the causal effect of the treatment variable?
A colleague shared results of a simulation that seem to indicate this.
Here is the setup:

A PS model was fit using multiple covariates, $X_1$, $X_2$, $...$, $X_n$
A 1:1 treated:untreated sample was created using propensity score matching from the model in step 1
Using the sample from step 2, a regression is fit with the following covariates, $treatment$, a subset of $X_1$, $X_2$, $...$, $X_n$, and an additional variable that wasn't in the PS model, $X_{additional}$

To me this seemed like it should adjust for confounding from $X_1$, $X_2$, $...$, $X_n$ and $X_{additional}$.
Is there some theoretical reason why this set of covariates in the outcome model would introduce bias to the estimated treatment effect that wouldn't exist if those covariates weren't included?

Why wouldn't you include that variable in the PS model? Even variables that predict the outcome and not the treatment belong in the PS model (as long as they are not caused by treatment).

It wasn't originally included for fear that it would prevent adequate overlap of PS scores between the treated and untreated.
